# Safe way to be sure if a comment request can be accepted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, comments

I'm working on a comment-list page for my website and I added some functions, like modifying the comment or deleting it.

Now I'm working on the part to let the user that posted a comment delete it, but I'm not sure that my proedure is safe.

I want to get everything working in AJAX, so I have a button that appears only if you are logged in and if the comment belongs to you.
In this case, if you click on the button, you open a modal where you have to confirm that you want to delete the comment.

If you confirm, you trigger an AJAX function that will call a php file that will modify a parameter in the comment that indicates that it doesn't have to be shown anymore.

Now the problem is that anyone can send a request for any comment-id and they'll delete it from the database. How can I make this procedure safer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure that A user has authority to delete their comment, link the user id to the comment and match it up to the user session when they are logged in.

Make sure you escape your comment with either prepared queries using pdo (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or escape the string using mysqli_escape_string (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php)

Comment: Can you explain more the first part? The comments in the database keep the user id but I'm not sure that I keep track of the user session

Comment: Also, does an AJAX request send also data from the user like $_SESSION variables?

Comment: And then I could pass all the sesion variables via the ajax but I should protect them from connection-sniffing...

Comment: Maybe look into oAuth authentication. This is a common method to secure requests. http://oauth.net/2/